# insert new data to oracle with python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle11g

```py
sql_query = "INSERT INTO cj_autonews (KEYWORDS, KEYSENTENCE) VALUES (:1, :2) where attach_file = :3;"

cursor.execute(sql_query, (count1['keywords'][0],count1['summary'][0],count1['filename'][0]))
```

DatabaseError:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

From all the research into this approach, it seems to be the right method...if I can just get it working! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon (`;`) from the end of your query.

Semicolon is actually the client-side statement delimiter. Oracle DB does not have any use for it.